# "До сих пор не верится" vs "Всё ещё не верится"

Tags: словоупотребление

> **До сих пор** не верится, что ты ...
>
> **Всё ещё** не верится, что ты ...
>
> **До сих пор всё ещё** не верится, что ...

I wonder how the two similar phrases "до сих пор" and "всё ещё" are nuanced in this specific sentence and if combining them together serves to emphasise its meaning?

Comment: The difference between "до сих пор не" and "всё ещё не" is miniscule if any.  You can use them interchangeably.  "До сих пор всё ещё" sounds odd.

Comment: "До сих пор" may refer to a longer timespan than "Все еще". "До сих пор не верится, что мой сын женат" (Still can't believe that my son is married) can be used years after the marriage, whereas "Все еще не верится ..." would me more used in mere days after marriage. Difference is small, though, and it wouldn't be a mistake to swap them at any time.

Comment: They all kind valid and equal. Just last one I would say "artificial". You will almost never hear that. `До сих пор` or `Всё ещё` is enough. I mean if you put them together that if you only want to highlight or I would say exaggerate.

Comment: The first two phrases are equivalent, the third one is wrong. "Buttery butter".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“До сих пор” — literally “until these times” — can exclude the present moment while “всё ещё” would tend to include it, but the present tense of the verb “верится” negates that difference in the sentences given, where both phrases are identical.

Compare:

До сих пор не пробовал я настоящего кофе! — as a compliment to the drink being currently enjoyed
Я всё ещё не пробовал настоящего кофе — and the one being currently consumed isn’t spectacular either

Combining the phrases sounds unnatural.

Comment: Hi. Is it just me, or does the version with "всё ещё" sound more emphatic?

Comment: Yor examples seem to defy your first statement "_“До сих пор” — literally “until these times” — can exclude the present moment while “всё ещё” would tend to include it_". Your example with "всё ещё" excludes the present moment while the example with "до сих пор" includes it.

Comment: @YellowSky Well no, when the speaker claims not to have tasted decent coffee, in the first of my examples the times of suffering from bad coffee have ended with the current cup and so exclude it, and in the second sentence they go on.

Answer (score 2):

> **До сих пор всё ещё** не верится

is a no-no, in Russian such use would be described as *масло масляное*, that is tautological.

To make it more palatable the pronoun **всё** could be dropped

> **До сих пор ещё** не верится

It's still not perfect, but acceptable.

Comment: Hi. Is it better to spell "всё ещё" rather than "всe ещe"?

Comment: @Alone-zee hi, i prefer using **Ё** but unfortunately in formally written Russian the established norm is to use Е instead, unless it creates ambiguity as in the case of **все** и **всё** etc, so the phrase could be spelled as **всё еще**. The place of the letter Ё in written language the has long been a subject of debates, the Russians have even facetiously rephrased the proverb 'to dot all i's' as 'to dot all Ё's', i DO use it in my writing when it's not gonna be subjected to editorial scrutiny

Comment: I would not be as categorical that combining "до сих пор всё ещё" is a no-no.  Ruscorpora has [some examples](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C4%EE%20%F1%E8%F5%20%EF%EE%F0%20%E2%F1%B8%20%E5%F9%B8&p=0) of its usage by well-known writers.

Comment: @Vitaly good to know, but would you yourself use them in this way? i would have cringed had i come across this phrasing in any book by any writer however esteemed s/he be, and also i believe noteworthy is the time period **most** of these references are from, which is pre-modern, but euphony is still not there regardless of the era

Comment: I, personally, could use it in a colloquial speech. However, I like your proposal better.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the first two versions are most often interchangeable despite the fact that **до сих пор** typically points at a longer time passed. Here's an example where **до сих пор** *can't* replace **всё ещё** (at least, that would sound unnatural). The reason is **до сих пор** is about a really substantial period of time while **всё ещё** can mean anything *just longer than immediate*.

> Пытаюсь осознать то, что ты *сейчас* рассказал. **Всё ещё не верится**, что
>   ты такое сделал.